# How do I partially update a field in MongoDB so the new field will add some text to exisiting record

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, amazon-s3

Given this document saved in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccd633576f5db0d40a2b0e4"),
    "image_url" :"images/test.jp"
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccd633576f5db0d40a2b0e4"),
    "image_url" :"images/test1.jp"
}
```

So i want to add image_url field some url like this
https://www.test.com/

and result should be

https://www.test.com/images/test.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Mongo v4.2+ theres a new [feature](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/coming-in-mongodb-42-pipeline-powered-updates-and-more-expressive-queries) which you can use to update documents using their fields:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ccd633576f5db0d40a2b0e4")
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
             "image_url": {$concat: ["https://www.test.com/", "$image_url"]}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

For older Mongo versions you're going to have to use code, first to read the document:

```
let doc = await db.collection.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5ccd633576f5db0d40a2b0e4")});
```

Then to update it using the read data:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        "_id" : doc._id
    },
    {
        "image_url": {$concat: ["https://www.test.com/", doc.image_url]}
    }
)
```

Multi update:

From the Mongo's [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

> By default, the db.collection.update() method updates a single document. Include the option multi: true to update all documents that match the query criteria.

So for Mongo version 4.2+ just add the multi flag and change your query to match:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        // query to match required documents. leave empty for all.
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
             "image_url": {$concat: ["https://www.test.com/", "$image_url"]}
            }
        }
    ],
    {
       multi: true
    }
)
```

Unfortunately for lesser Mongo versions due to the fact that you cant use documents values while updating that means you're going to have to read each one and update each one separately.

Comment: Hi Tom unfortunately this query is working only one record How About if i want to Update Multiple Records at once

Comment: I edited my answer to include the multi option, note that its only viable for Mongo version 4.2+

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bulk update also

var bulkOp = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulkOp.find({}).update({ $set: { 'image_url': {$concat: ["https://www.test.com/",    "$image_url"]} } });

bulkOp.execute();